# Junk values in deletion of circular linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

The structure and function that deletes a node in a circular linked list is as follows:

```
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node *next;
    };

    struct node *head = NULL;

void add(int n)
{
    struct node *temp=NULL,*trav=head;
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = n;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        temp->next = temp;
        head = temp;
        return;
    }
    while(trav->next!=head)
        trav = trav->next;
    trav->next = temp;
    temp->next = head;
}

void delete(int x)
{
    struct node *temp=head,*rem=NULL;
    if(head!=NULL)
    {
        if(head->data==x)
        {
            while(temp->next!=head)
                temp = temp->next;
            rem=head;
            head = head->next;
            temp->next = head;
            free(rem);
        }
        else
        {
            while(temp->data!=x)
            {
                rem = temp;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            rem->next = temp->next;
            free(temp);
        }
    }
    else
        printf("List is empty");
}

void print()
{
    struct node *temp=head;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty");
        return;
    }
    printf("\n The List is: ");
    do
    {
        printf(" %d ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }while(temp!=head);
}
```

The main function calls are shown below:

```
int main(void)
{
    add(1);
    add(2);
    add(3);
    add(4);
    add(5);
    print();
    delete(1);
    delete(2);
    delete(3);
    delete(4);
    delete(5);
    print();
}
```

Output:

[image]

All the nodes are deleted but, finally a junk value is printed. What is wrong in my function?

Comment: give the implementation of add function.

Comment: During deletion you aren't handling the case when there will be one element left

Comment: If only one element is left and it is deleted, then head should be NULL. You are not explicitly taking care of this.

Comment: there is another problem in your code, if you delete a node which `x` is not exist in your list, your program will suck. such as `delete(8)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your list becomes empty, i.e. you delete the last element in the list, you need to set `head = NULL;`.

A simple fix might be to replace:

```
void delete(int x)
{
    struct node *temp=head,*rem=NULL;
    if(head!=NULL)
    {
        if(head->data==x)
```

with:

```
void delete(int x)
{
    struct node *temp=head,*rem=NULL;
    if(head!=NULL)
    {
        if(head==head->next && head->data==x)
        {
            free(head);
            head=NULL;
        }
        else if(head->data==x)
```

I didn't actually run this, so I may not have covered all the cases.